# PySide QThread controlling QWebView from different class / QThread

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside, qthread

I've looked and looked all over internet.
I'm trying to use QThread in PySide Python, change website/control JS via separate thread. In code bellow, I am trying change QUrl after 5 seconds, reload page.
Do I need to use QObjectName? How to target QWebView created in MainWindow.
I'm doing something really wrong.

```
import time
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)

          web_window = QWebView()
          #default website at startup
          web_window.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
          web_window.show()

          thread = Thread()
          thread.start()

          sys.exit(app.exec_())


class Thread(QThread):

      def __init__(self):
          QThread.__init__(self)
          print("Thread initialized")

      def run(self):
          print("Thread is running....")

          time.sleep(2) #in 2 seconds open different page
          web_window.load(QUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/"))

          #time.sleep(5) #in 5 seconds open different page
          web_window.load(QUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"))

          #do more thread code here...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = MainWindow()
```

Keep getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\software\stackoverflow-sample.py", line 33, in run
>   web_window.load(QUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/")) NameError: global name
>   'web_window' is not defined

Comment: Qt does not support any gui operations outside of the main thread. So it is not safe to directly call the methods of widgets from a non-gui thread. If you want to periodically reload or change the page, use a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html).

Comment: Thank you! :)
I resolve this issue --- with SIGNAL / CONNECT.

Answer (score 0):

All solved.
Here's different code with - QThread connects to main GUI (reload website or anything). Following page tremendously helped: https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/

```
import sys, time
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class ThreadSignal(QObject):
        sig = Signal(str)

class ThreadMain(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.send2thread_signal = ThreadSignal()

    def run(self):
        cc=1
        while (cc > 0):
            cc = cc + 1
            self.send2thread_signal.sig.emit( 'Message #: %s' % cc )

            time.sleep(0.5)

            if (cc == 10):
                print("Time to kill thread")
                cc=-1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        print("GUI: Startup & Init")

        self.thread = ThreadMain()
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.started.connect(self.gui_hello)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.finished)
        self.thread.send2thread_signal.sig.connect(self.threadcommunication) #thread communication


    def gui_hello(self):
        print("GUI: Thread started." )

    def finished(self):
        print("GUI: Thread finished.")

    def threadcommunication(self,message_from_thread):
        print("GUI: Message from QThread: %s" % message_from_thread )


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```